# Cannot add or update a child row(new in mysql workbench)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am making a project on medical shop. 
I have made three tables which are as follows:

- customer
- medicine
- medSold

I want to connect these tables in such a way that the `medsold` table can fetch the data from both `medicine` table and `customer` table.

the EER diagram is as follows:
[image]

when I am executing the following query:

```
insert into medSold(medsold_id,med_id,c_id,generic_name,brand_name,mft_date,exp_date,billing_date,med_name) values ('','','','sumthing1','dntknw1','2012-11-10','2014-12-20','','crocine');
```

it is giving the following error:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mysql1`.`medSold`, CONSTRAINT `c_id` FOREIGN KEY (`c_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`c_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

why its happening?

Comment: you have to insert relevant row in your customer table too.

Comment: sorry,..Now I am not able to define the foreign key in the child table..                                                             its showing error..:                                            ERROR 1050: Table 'medSold' already exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable foreign key checks if you forcefully want to insert records.

set foreign_key_checks=0;
insert into medSold(medsold_id,med_id,c_id,generic_name,brand_name,mft_date,exp_date,billing_date,med_name) values ('','','','sumthing1','dntknw1','2012-11-10','2014-12-20','','crocine');
set foreign_key_checks=1;

Comment: Brilliant, you made my day. My query was too long and when i  do insert one by one all good. But full one never worked until i disable foreign key check.

Answer (score 0):

Check that c_id is the same on both tables(type, size, not null and unsigned flags) and make sure that customer table contains the key you're reffering to.

Also, if you want to make foreign key empty, use (NULL) instead of ''

Answer (score 0):

This is basic error in foriegn key relations.

You must insert records in your parent tables before inserting the child table..

There is no c_id in the child table that you try to enter in foreign key table..

Comment: No it's the other way round: you first need to insert into the parent table, then into the child table.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;
insert into medSold(medsold_id,med_id,c_id,generic_name,brand_name,mft_date,exp_date,billing_date,med_name) values ('','','','sumthing1','dntknw1','2012-11-10','2014-12-20','','crocine');
set foreign_key_checks=1;
```

This will disable the foreign key.